# How to add Serial No. to first column of specific Table only

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

I have many tables on dashboard also I have `fullCalender`(`fullCalender` uses table on UI) on dashboard. All I need is to have serial number in first column of specific table only, it can be identified by either `id` or `class`,

```
<style>
  table { counter-reset: Serial; }
  table { border-collapse: separate; }
  tr td:first-child:before { counter-increment: Serial; content: counter(Serial).; }
</style>
```

but it give serial numbers to all the table that exists on UI including `fullCalender`. To support question below is the image.

[image]

Comment: You are applying css the the element. Why dont you apply to a class and add the class to the tables you want to have a serial no.?

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished it using below css code,

```
<style>
  .serialTable { counter-reset: Serial; }
  .serialTable { border-collapse: separate; }
  .serialTable tr td:first-child:before { counter-increment: Serial; content: counter(Serial); }
</style>
```

then I added class `serialTable` to required table as `<table class="serialTable"></table>`